# Where can I include the Google Analytics event tracking code on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

The button code on the website goes like this:

```
    <button class="book-button" id="callButton">PHONE NUMBER</button>
```

This button is available on many pages, with the same class and id.

I want to track the number of clicks on this button (irrespective of which page it is on), and I have set up an event in Google Analytics with the following parameters:

```
Category= button;
Action= call;
Label= right-top;
```

I am new to this, and wanted to know where to put the event tracking code from Google in the button code.

Thank you!

Comment: Use a click event handler …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, as pointed to in the comments:

```
<button class="book-button" id="callButton" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'call', 'right-top');">PHONE NUMBER</button>
```

but this would be specific to the "top right" button only. I think that if your site isn't terribly complex at the moment (and assuming you aren't using GTM), you could migrate to GTM and track that button and other user engagement points, which would free you from using inline code.

Comment: thanks! I have added the code, and the numbers are reflecting correctly in Real Time > Events. For some reason though, there is no data under Behavior > Events > Overview, and same case for Conversion > Goals > Overview. Does it take more time for the data to flow to the above 2 sections?

Comment: You need to allow up to 24 hours for data to be processed into your reports. You should, however, see goal conversion and event data in real time. Also can you show how your goal is configured?

Comment: Oh okay. I hope this is what you mean by how the goal is configured:Goal setup is Custom; Type is Event and Category/ Action/ Label values are button/ call/ right-top.